# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Remove the specific Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to remove specific **Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor** for the whole document.
First, I tried to
find all ranges from MS word with specific **Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor** which has been programmatically set as **WdColor.wdColorLavender** for some paragraphs. It includes normal text, space /empty paragraph,  I tried the **find.Execute()** method with following code

```
find.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = WordNs.WdColor.wdColorLavender;
find.Font.Color = WordNs.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic;
find.Text = string.Empty;
find.Forward = isForward;
find.Format = true;
find.MatchCase = false;
find.MatchWildcards = false;
find.MatchSoundsLike = false;
find.MatchAllWordForms = false;
```

but it cannot get the **Space**, **Empty Paragraph** which also set the **Shading.BackgroundPatternColor**.

For the removing part, I use the following code:

```
item.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = WordNs.WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight;
```

Is there any other way to get all document range by **Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor** and remove it?

Comment: Try to use "^p^p" in text for finding empty paragraphs. Please refer the macro example in this link (https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DeleteEmptyParas.htm) and this link (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/647-word-remove-empty-paragraphs.html)

Comment: Thanks Surenthar, but I can't do other modification for word doc except for removing the Shading.BackgroundPatternColor, is there any other way to find all ranges through Shading.BackgroundPatternColor?

Comment: You misunderstood the suggestion. Surenthar doesn't propose you replace anything, just that you use the approach in that link to *find* the "empty" paragraphs so that the formatting can be applied.